# Negative height calculated from a PDF link's Rect

Tags: pdf

I am working on extraction of links and theirs locations from a PDF document.

Each link has a bounding Rect.

```
<</A 169 0 R/BS<</S/S/Type/Border/W 0>>/Border[0 0 0]/H/N/Rect[97.0153 116.556 185.543 21.5209]/Subtype/Link/Type/Annot>>
```

Let's look at `Rect[97.0153 116.556 185.543 21.5209]` (I got it by copying from my file).

> Rectangle is an array of four numbers in default user space units giving the
> coordinates of the left, bottom, right and top edges respectively.

So we have `left = 97.0153`, `bottom = 116.556`, `right = 185.543`, `top = 21.5209`.

As far as I know PDF's user space is a regular Cartesian coordinate system. Therefore,
I expect that the rect's top edge is greater than the bottom's one, so when I want to calculate the rect's height, I use the formula `height = top - bottom`. For that particular PDF document `height = 21.5209 - 116.556 = -95.036`, i.e. height is negative and I do something wrong.

I must have missed something and made wrong assumptions. Can anybody advise, please?

Comment: In practice, you should "normalize" any rectangle.  They are often written incorrectly.  The smaller number is the bottom, the larger number is the top.

Comment: As @dirck said, you always should normalize. Depending on where you look, you'll often find **Rect** merely as being characterized as a *rectangle* which in turn _shall be written as an array of four numbers giving the coordinates of a pair of diagonally opposite corners._

Comment: (By the way, where did you get that "... giving the coordinates of the left, bottom, right and top edges respectively" characterization? I had something like that in the back of my mind, too, but could only find it for **BBox** entries.)

Comment: @mkl Yes, I got it from `BBox` entry description, too. `BBox` is declared to have type `rectangle` and provided with description if `rectangle`. PDF Rfeference, 3rd edition, p. 616. So I suppose all rectangles in PDF have the same definition.

Comment: Just a related note: Acrobat is very forgiving of what it finds in PDF files.  Various PDF publishing/editing programs often have bugs and violate the spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning your characterization

> Rectangle is an array of four numbers in default user space units giving the coordinates of the left, bottom, right and top edges respectively.

you said in a comment

> I got it from **BBox** entry description, too. **BBox** is declared to have type *rectangle* and provided with description if *rectangle*. PDF Rfeference, 3rd edition, p. 616.

But the **BBox** entry description is not the *definition* of the **rectangle** type. The *definition* is on page 101:

> #### 3.8.3 Rectangles
>
> Rectangles are used to describe locations on a page and bounding boxes for a variety of objects, such as fonts. A rectangle is written as an array of four numbers giving the coordinates of a pair of diagonally opposite corners. Typically, the array takes the form
>
> *[ll<sub>x</sub> ll<sub>y</sub> ur<sub>x</sub> ur<sub>y</sub>]*
>
> specifying the lower-left x, lower-left y, upper-right x, and upper-right y coordinates of the rectangle, in that order.
>
> ***Note:** Although rectangles are conventionally specified by their lower-left and upper-right corners, it is acceptable to specify any two diagonally opposite corners. Applications that process PDF should be prepared to normalize such rectangles in situations where specific corners are required.*

Thus, the characterization you found for the **BBox** entries makes the *typical* form required for that **BBox** entry. Other rectangles, though, may still use a non-typical form. Thus, you need to normalize the array (or in your case, take the absolute value of that difference as height).

As an aside, I wouldn't count on **BBox** entries to always be in that *typical* form, either. Always be prepared to normalize rectangle arrays.

---

That being said you should do yourself a favor and not use that old PDF Reference from 2001 anymore but instead use an ISO norm specifying PDF, i.e. ISO 32000-1 or ISO 32000-2. ISO 32000-1 has been published in 2008. ISO 32000-2 has been published in 2017 and updated in 2020.

If you don't want to spend money on the specification, Adobe has shared a copy of ISO 32000-1 with the ISO page headers removed on their web site. To find it, simply search for "PDF32000"; currently it is at https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf

The only situation in which the PDF 1.4 Reference should still be used is in context with norms based on that very Reference, e.g. PDF/A-1. Otherwise the PDF References are obsolete and had already before been called *not normative in nature* by the Adobe PDF architect Leonard Rosenthol.